# Android application bug report

Tags: android, exception

Any ideas how can I create a bug report in my application and when application crash to open a dialog and give the user a chance to send us report with files attached to the e-mail and etc. I've already implemented a function which is sending the error message to out server, but I want to be able to let the user to send these errors with some text input, attached files and etc.

Any ideas how should I proceed?

Answer (score 4):

You can find exactly what you're looking for in [Instabug](https://instabug.com). It is a bug & crash reporting SDK that allows for two things:

- Allows users to report bugs through a shake gesture in-app

  - Upon a shake, a screenshot is taken that the user can draw on for visual bug identification.
  - User can further describe the bug using text, extra screenshots, voice notes, or even screen recordings.
- Automatically receive crash reports in the event of a crash

All reports arrive to your Instabug dashboard containing various details such as:

- Network and console logs
- Complete Device details
- Visual reproduction steps
- Crash stack trace (In case of a crash report)

It only takes a line of code to integrate.

---

For full disclosure, I work at Instabug. Let me know if I can help.

Answer (score 1):

See [ACRA](http://acra.ch/). It's a solid crash reporting library.

You can get more information than the reports in Google Play, and there are a lot of configuration options detailing just which info you want and how you want it delivered. Default is to upload spreadsheets into Google docs.

Also allows user input at crash time.